# Gutenberg blocks and page templates

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, theme-development

I developed a pretty complex site with many different page templates, where I echo a lot of custom post-type content, as well as ACF flexible content. Now I would like to create some custom Gutenberg blocks for the site, but I'm not sure how it would fit in with the code I already have in the page templates. As an example, I would like to create a graph using Gutenberg blocks, that would display after an events section that I'm echoing out in the page template.

I'm not sure how that would work. Should I create a Gutenberg block for the custom post type? Does anyone have any experience with mixing things like flexible content and Gutenberg? Is it worth using Gutenberg on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg receives another update with version 12.7. With peeled eyes, especially after the launch of WordPress version 5.9 with much-awaited full-site editing, block themes, and much more.

Gutenberg 12.7 offers intuitive and necessary enhancements that will make working with patterns even easier! Let’s see what version 12.7 of Gutenberg holds for us.

The list view keeps getting interesting updates. Now there is an option to select multiple blocks. You can do this by holding the shift key and clicking on multiple blocks to select them. One can also use the up and down arrows ↕️ to select multiple blocks.

All this goes on to increase the block editor experience, and provide a more effective way to drag and drop blocks, change multiple blocks into a group or a list, etc.

Gutenberg version 12.6 got improved and enhanced block transform features. This includes maintaining font size and color while selecting between different blocks like list, quote, etc.

Gutenberg 12.7 adds custom CSS classes to this, allowing you to maintain custom block styles.

A article from [WPWhiteBoard](https://wpwhiteboard.com/its-raining-blocks-in-wordpress-the-gutenberg-12-7-version-is-here/) might help you in this. Have a look. If it not helps you, do reply in this thread. I will try my best to resolve your query.